# What event is fired when I change an element on the observable collection?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection

I have a data grid in my view that binds to an observable collection in my view model.

When I do this:

```
myObservableCollection[2] = myItem;
```

The data grid refresh the items, and for example, if I have shorted the elements in the data grid, if `myItem` has updated a field that is affected by the short, is put in its new position.

However, I would like to scroll to the new position, so I am trying to use an attached behavior, that is works good when the event selection changed is fired, but I need to know what event is fired when I reasign `myItem`.

I have try to catch the events `AddingNewItem` and `SourceUpdated`, but neither of them is fired.

Comment: CollectionChanged event is fired. It's arguments contain old and newvalues as well as their indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netaholic gave a good part of the answer, but just to complete and put some clear visible code :

```
public void Demo()
{
    ObservableCollection<String> collec = new ObservableCollection<String>() {"hello"};
    collec.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
    collec[0] = "goodbye";
}
void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            Debug.WriteLine("The event you re expecting");
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In the second parameter, you 'll find the index and object that is replaced

Regards